# Display message in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am a beginner in C#, ASP.NET.
What i want is when clicks 'submit' button, need to display a message 'Your registration is succesful'.
But When i clicks here, nothing showing, but it showing message in other pc with same code.
Somebody can help me ? is there any configuration errors in my project ?

code here:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Windows.Forms;
public partial class Registration : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

}
protected void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("Your registration is succesful"); // Not displaying
    //MessageBox.Show("Test Display");
}
```

}

ASP.NET

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
    <table class="style1">
        <tr>
            <td class="style3">
                Username</td>
            <td class="style6">
                <asp:TextBox ID="uname" runat="server" Width="180px"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td class="style8">
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" 
                    ControlToValidate="uname" ErrorMessage="Username is required" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="style3">
                Email</td>
            <td class="style6">
                <asp:TextBox ID="email" runat="server" Width="180px"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td class="style8">
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" 
                    ControlToValidate="email" ErrorMessage="Email is required" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                <br />
                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" 
                    ControlToValidate="email" ErrorMessage="You must enter the valid email id" 
                    ForeColor="Red" 
                    ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="style3">
                Password</td>
            <td class="style6">
                <asp:TextBox ID="pass" runat="server" TextMode="Password" Width="180px"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td class="style8">
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" 
                    ControlToValidate="pass" ErrorMessage="Password is required" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="style3">
                Confirm Password</td>
            <td class="style6">
                <asp:TextBox ID="passr" runat="server" TextMode="Password" Width="180px"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td class="style8">
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" 
                    ControlToValidate="passr" ErrorMessage="Confirm password is required" 
                    ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                <br />
                <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server" 
                    ControlToCompare="pass" ControlToValidate="passr" 
                    ErrorMessage="Both passwords must be same" ForeColor="Red"></asp:CompareValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="style3">
                Country</td>
            <td class="style6">
                <asp:DropDownList ID="country" runat="server" Width="180px">
                    <asp:ListItem>Select Country</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>USA</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>UK</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>GERMANY</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>FRANCE</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>INDIA</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </td>
            <td class="style8">
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" runat="server" 
                    ControlToValidate="country" ErrorMessage="Select a country name" 
                    ForeColor="Red" InitialValue="Select Country"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="style4">
            </td>
            <td class="style7">
                <asp:Button ID="submit" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
            </td>
            <td class="style5">
                <input id="Reset1" type="reset" value="reset" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="style2">
                &nbsp;</td>
            <td class="style6">
                &nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                &nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
```

Comment: `MessageBox` is only local to the web server its running on and shouldn't be used with asp.net

Comment: Upon what computer do you believe the message box should be shown? The fact that you believe this code does something useful indicates that you might have a conceptual problem with how ASP.NET works. ASP runs code on the *server* which sends *text* to the *client*. Is that model clear?

Comment: There is no `MessageBox.Show` in `ASP.NET`

Comment: Really sorry, I have made a big mistake, I FORGOT TO remove MessageBox.Show("Test Display");  My problem is    Response.Write("Your registration is succesful"); is not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to understand the difference between server-side and client-side.

Server-side is everything that happens on the server (e.g. ASP, ASP.NET, PHP) that is used to create the HTML that is sent to the browser. It also deals with the information that is returned by the browser when the user submits stuff back (the post-back).

Client-side is everything that happens on the browser once the HTML has been received, or when user does something on the page like clicking an element.

What you are doing is trying to run a Windows Application style `MessageBox.Show` **on** the server... that's not going to work.

If you want the browser to display an "alert" window (a bit like a `MessageBox`) then you need to send client-side script to the browser.  Try this...

```
protected void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("Your registration is succesful");
    var script = "window.alert('Test Display');";
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "message", script, true);
}
```

---

As per the comment by the OP...

> My problem is Response.Write("Your registration is succesful"); is not working

Instead of using `Response.Write` use a `<asp:Literal>` control (which gives you the advantage of positioning the control exactly where you need it) and set the `.Text` property of it (remember that this will remain on post-back, so you might need to clear it).

You could also use a `<asp:Label>` which would not only allow you to position it, but you can also including `.CssClass` or `.Style` attributes for better formatting.

Comment: Thanks for your consideration and time..Really sorry, I have made a big mistake, I FORGOT TO remove MessageBox.Show("Test Display"); My problem is Response.Write("Your registration is succesful"); is not working

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show confirmation message box try to use jquery on your .aspx page. You can add function like this

```
function confirmationAccept() {
    return confirm("Accept?");
}
```

And than add properties onclientclick like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="addButton" runat="server" Text="Add"  OnClientClick="return confirmationAccept()">
```

Comment: Really sorry, I have made a big mistake, I FORGOT TO remove MessageBox.Show("Test Display"); My problem is Response.Write("Your registration is succesful"); is not working

Answer (score 0):

You can show javascript alert message by using `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript`.

Comment: Really sorry, I have made a big mistake, I FORGOT TO remove MessageBox.Show("Test Display"); My problem is Response.Write("Your registration is succesful"); is not working